# How can I reassign the value and placeholder properties of Clerk's SignIn component?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, clerk

On Clerk's documentation, it shows how to get access to the input field by using the appearance prop like so

```
<SignIn 
      appearance={{
        elements: {
          formFieldInput: 'bg-zinc-300/30'
        }
      }}/>
```

But I'm trying to change the default value of the input field to be a username for a demo account on a project I'm building

I've tried adding a placeholder object under formFieldInput like this

```
      <SignIn 
      appearance={{
        elements: {
          formFieldInput: {
            placeholder: 'test'
          }
        }
      }}/>
```

Which provides no errors, but also doesn't have any result on the rendered component.
Similarly, I tried adjusting the value that way, as well as like this

```
      <SignIn 
      appearance={{
        elements: {
          formFieldInput: placeholder: 'test'
        }
      }}/>
```

and

```
      <SignIn 
      value='demo'
      appearance={{
        elements: {
          formFieldInput: placeholder: 'test'
        }
      }}/>
```

Which shows a Parsing error: ',' expected. And If I replace the semicolon with a comma, it cannot find the name 'placeholder'.

I can change these values through the DOM by inspecting, and selecting the input element, then setting the placeholder or value properties to any string, but I'm not sure how to do it from the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

The SignIn accepts an Initial Values also you can use that

Answer (score -1):

I think those props are only for customizing css styles. I dont think anywhere it shows in docs how u would be able to change placeholder options

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35553556)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).